# How to use a passive POE injector with Huawei AP

Tags: wireless-access-point, power-over-ethernet

I have a passive injector in the picture below. I want to power my Huawei AP5030DN. I tried plugging the 12V power adapter to the injector and nothing happened. I tried a 24V adapter that I found and still nothing happened. How could I run this AP with this injector? By the way I tested the AP and it works.

[image: Injector]

Comment: How is this injector device *"passive"*?  Instead of just a photo, post the actual model number of the item.  FYI PoE typically uses 48VDC, and not 12V or 24V.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a model number or anything similar. I just found this injector.

Answer (score 1):

IEEE 802.3 PoE (802.af/at/bt) uses ~48V with active device discovery - power is only applied when a compatible device is sensed. That passive injector doesn't do that.

You'll need to either get an injector that is compatible with 802.3 PoE and provides sufficient power.

Using such a passive injector requires an appropriate, passive splitter on the other end. Using such passive PoE devices removes two cable pairs from communication and leaves you with a cable that's only good for 100BASE-TX or 10BASE-T. 1000BASE-T requires all four pairs to carry data.

Also, passive injectors provide power to their cable pins at all times, regardless of what you connect. If used with incompatible equipment (there isn't really a standard) they can cause permanent damage. In contrast, IEEE 802.3 have taken great care to design their standards so that incompatible devices are not inflicted.